# how to change the value of column of grid dynamically in extjs

Tags: extjs

> Blockquote

```
header:WtfGlobal.getLocaleText("hrms.performance.self.rating"),
              dataIndex:'gemprat',
              sortable:true,
              renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                  debugger;
                  var val = record.get('gemprat');
                  console.log(val); 
                  if (val === '5') {
                      record.set('gemprat', 'CEE');
                  } 
              }
```

> Blockquote
>   please help me to alter this value

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is this the data in the store or the actual values that should be shown based on the `gemprat` field value?

Comment: A renderer isn't an appropriate place to be doing that.

Comment: gemprat- its a column name.  i will get the value of that column  like 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5, grid has number of row,has number of record,  now i just want to alter the value of that column. if 1 then it must be show "NME", if 2 then it must me show "UME".

Answer (score 1):

> A  column renderer is an 'interceptor' method which can be used to transform
>   data (value, appearance, etc.) before it is rendered. The return value
>   is the HTML string to be rendered.

First of all, create an object from data array for easy access.

```
var data = [['5','CEE' ],['4','GEE'],['3','ME'],['2','UME'],['1','NME']];
var newDataObj = {};
data.forEach(function(a){ newDataObj[a[0]]=a[1]; });
```

Creates an Object with values as {1: "NME", 2: "UME", 3: "ME", 4: "GEE", 5: "CEE"}

If data array is static, you can directly create an object with above data.

Now change your renderer function as shown below.

```
 renderer: function(value, meta, record) {        
     // var val = record.get('gemprat'); No need for this line since dataIndex for this column is gemprat.
      return newDataObj[value];
  }
```